# Duplicate Content in HTML Email Outlook 2007

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, outlook-2007

I'm experiencing a bizarre phenomenon in Outlook 2007.  An image and some text is being partially duplicated for no apparent reason.  Has anyone experienced anything similar?  Any possible solutions?  Here is a screen shot:

http://img38.imageshack.us/img38/7512/duplicatecontentoutlook.jpg

Here is the code:

```
<TR vAlign=top>
<TD style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; PADDING-BOTTOM: 10px; PADDING-LEFT: 5px; PADDING-RIGHT: 5px; PADDING-TOP: 10px" vAlign=top align=middle>
<P><IMG src="tw.jpg" width=200 height=150></P>
<P style="FONT-FAMILY: trebuchet ms, geneva; FONT-SIZE: xx-small">Professor Thomas Walde depicted in a mosaic portrait, kindly commissioned and donated by Maher Boktor of Alexandria University, Egypt</P>
</TD>
<TD style="TEXT-ALIGN: left; FONT-FAMILY: trebuchet ms, geneva; FONT-SIZE: small PADDING-BOTTOM: 10px; PADDING-LEFT: 5px; PADDING-RIGHT: 5px; PADDING-TOP: 10px" vAlign=top align=middle>
<P><STRONG>A Liber Amicorum: Thomas Walde - Law Beyond Conventional Thought</STRONG></P>
<P>This book was published in honour of Thomas Wälde.&nbsp; The editors Jacques Werner and Arif Hyder Ali gathered an impressive collection of essays by practitioners, arbitrators and professors who knew Thomas in a modest effort to capture his never ending interests.</P>
<P>This book is now available on OGEL and TDM with the kind permission from the publisher, CMP Publishing Ltd.&nbsp; Individual chapters can be downloaded <A href="http://www.ogel.org/journal-browse-issues-toc.asp?key=46">here</A> while the whole book is available for download <A href="http://www.ogel.org/liber-amicorum.asp">here</A></P>
</TD>
</TR>
```

Thanks,

John

Edit: I'm using a version of TinyMCE HTML Editor.

Comment: Show the entire html of the email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've figured out what was causing the duplication, but I have no idea WHY it was happening.  I reverted to a previous problem-free version of the email and gradually added things in until the problem re-surfaced.  The offending piece of code was:

```
FONT-SIZE: xx-small;
```

from the following line:

```
<P style="FONT-FAMILY: trebuchet ms, geneva; FONT-SIZE: xx-small">Professor Thomas Walde depicted in a mosaic portrait, kindly commissioned and donated by Maher Boktor of Alexandria University, Egypt</P>
```

I have font-size: xx-small; in other areas of the document and they weren't causing duplication, so I have no idea why this one is problematic. But removing it fixes the problem.

Edit: I changed it to font-size: 8pt; and the problem re-appears!!

Comment: After working with HTML emails and outlook for a while, I've finally discovered why this happens. Since outlook uses word to render emails, it has the concept of page breaks. If you have an image spanning a page break then funny things start to happen, such as duplication or big gaps. The only solution I know is to re-arrange the content, so that images don't lie on the page break areas.